# How to use ng-repeat track by using ClientID inside Json

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is the code which i have in my controller..I have used 2  elements in the json and passed it to scope.

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.response=
  [
    [{
      "VisitName":"Brand",
    "ClientName":"Software Solutions",
    "POC":" Name",
    "ClientID":"1",
    "Phone":"9884563143",
    "logID":null,
    "empID":"1",
    "Active":null,
    "Code":null,
    "dat":null},
  {
    "VisitName":"Service",
    "ClientName":"Software Solutions",
    "POC":"Name",
    "ClientID":"2",
    "Phone":"9884563143",
    "logID":null,
    "empID":"1",
    "Active":null,
    "Code":null,
    "dat":null
}]
]

});
```

```html
Below is the html code which i used to repeat json array.. 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Service</title>


    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-material.min.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <div ng-controller="customersCtrl" ng-cloak>
 <h1>Values</h1>
 <ul class="chosen" dnd-list="model">
      <li ng-repeat="chosen in response track by chosen.ClientID">
        {{chosen.VisitName}}
           {{chosen.Phone}}
           {{chosen.POC}}
      </li>
  </ul>
    <!-- <div>
     <span>{{response}}</span>
   </div>
   <span>{{error}}</span>-->
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

There is not output comes in the html page, searched all examples and stackoverflow solutions, but i can't find the exact solutions guys, Please help me guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have array in array at `$scope.response`
just use only one array

`$scope.response= [{...},{...}]`

or chose first element in array at template (if you cant change `$scope.response`)

`<li ng-repeat="chosen in response[0] track by chosen.ClientID">`

```js
var app = angular.module('starter', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.response=
  [
    [{
      "VisitName":"Brand",
    "ClientName":"Software Solutions",
    "POC":" Name",
    "ClientID":"1",
    "Phone":"9884563143",
    "logID":null,
    "empID":"1",
    "Active":null,
    "Code":null,
    "dat":null},
  {
    "VisitName":"Service",
    "ClientName":"Software Solutions",
    "POC":"Name",
    "ClientID":"2",
    "Phone":"9884563143",
    "logID":null,
    "empID":"1",
    "Active":null,
    "Code":null,
    "dat":null
}]
]

});
```

```html
Below is the html code which i used to repeat json array.. 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Service</title>


    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.3/angular-material.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.3/angular-material.jss"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <div ng-controller="customersCtrl" ng-cloak>
 <h1>Values</h1>
 <ul class="chosen" dnd-list="model">
      <li ng-repeat="chosen in response[0] track by chosen.ClientID">
        {{chosen.VisitName}}
           {{chosen.Phone}}
           {{chosen.POC}}
      </li>
  </ul>
    <!-- <div>
     <span>{{response}}</span>
   </div>
   <span>{{error}}</span>-->
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi guys, this above worked when i use in separate project. when i include it in my whole project it is not adapting don't know why..?? 1. I am using ng-view,using different controllers for different views, 2.using web service in factory to get the values $scope.response ABOVE and store,retrieve, and getting it.. 3. i am getting this stored values in one controller and using it in one html page, it is not showing anything..

Answer (score 1):

It's because response is an array of an array not just a single dimension array get rid of the extra angle brackets:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl',function($scope){
  $scope.response=
  [
   {
      "VisitName":"Brand",
    "ClientName":" Software Solutions",
    "POC":"Name",
    "ClientID":"1",
    "Phone":"9884563143",
    "logID":null,
    "empID":"1",
    "Active":null,
    "Code":null,
    "dat":null},
  {
    "VisitName":"Service",
    "ClientName":"Software Solutions",
    "POC":"Name",
    "ClientID":"2",
    "Phone":"9884563143",
    "logID":null,
    "empID":"1",
    "Active":null,
    "Code":null,
    "dat":null
}
];

});
```

Comment: Thank you Gabriel's I will check on it.. Can you please suggest Any other other way other that this.. Can we add array name for this.. ?? And how